# What are the significant digits, when the standard deviation is larger than the value?

Tags: conventions, error-analysis

Let's say I have some quantity $a = 1.234\,a.u.$ with a standard deviation of $\sigma = 123.4\,a.u.$. How do I express the uncertainty in this case?

- $a = (1.2\pm 123.4)\,a.u.$
- $a = (0.0\pm1.2)\times10^2\,a.u.$
- $a = (0\pm120)\,a.u.$
- $a = (1.2\pm120)\,a.u.$
- Something else

Comment: You just say , that you have no idea of the magnitude of a, just that its less than 124 units

Comment: Technically you do not know the exact value of anything to 100% confidence. So in this case you would report the 90%/95%/99% confidence interval for that value.

Comment: I do understand how confidence intervals work. My question is on how to express those intervals in the case that they are larger than the expectation value. Which digits are significant, on which digit do I round?

Comment: The second one looks the nicest to me but there's nothing wrong with the others. The purpose of significant figures is to implicitly communicate an error bar. If you know the error bar anyway, you can just report it without playing that game.

Comment: The convention I have been following so far, assuming that the standard deviation $\sigma $ is smaller than the expectation value $\mu$, is the following: Round $\mu$ to the first decimal place of $ \sigma$ , i.e. $\mu = 3.53$ and $\sigma = 0.57$ $\Rightarrow$ $3.5\pm0.6$, unless the  specified digit is 1(2.x, x<5). In this case you show 2 significant digits in $\sigma$, i.e. $\mu = 1.235$ and $\sigma = 0.44$ $\Rightarrow$ $1.24\pm0.44$. However, when applying this convention to $\sigma$ greater than $\mu$ you might end up rounding $\mu$ down to zero. Does this make sense?

Comment: it depends if a can have negative values , if not neither 1± 100 nor 0 ±100 make sense.

Comment: The observable is not limited, in my case.

Comment: To answer the question more information is needed as to the process by which the value and its standard deviation was obtained. So please provide an indication of the data from which the final result was obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official recommendations can be found in section 7 of the BIPM's "Guide to the expression of uncertainty in measurement"

https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/2071204/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf/cb0ef43f-baa5-11cf-3f85-4dcd86f77bd6

It recommends to avoid the use of the ± symbol entirely unless you are reporting a confidence interval or what they call an expanded uncertainty. Their recommendation would be something like:

"$a = 1.2 \mathrm{\ a.u.}$ with a combined standard uncertainty $u_c = 120 \mathrm{\ a.u.}$"

Comment: Thank you, that document is quite illuminating. Additionally, I also find this source: [ICSBEP Guide to the Expression of Uncertainties](https://www.oecd-nea.org/science/wpncs/icsbep/documents/UncGuide.pdf), in particular section 3, to be helpful.

Comment: @Spyro thank, that is interesting. I have not seen that reference before. I usually use the BIPM one I cited or the NIST reference: https://www.nist.gov/pml/nist-technical-note-1297 but the ICSBEP one is new to me